# how to change an image in the hyperlink corresponding to the active page?

Tags: css, hyperlink, html

> **EDITING QUESTION TO ADD THE HTML -**>

```
<li><a href="about.php"><img src="images/about.png" width="16" height="16" />ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="mission.php"><img src="images/mission.png" width="16" height="16" />MISSION</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php"><img src="images/contact.png" width="16" height="16" />CONTACT</a></li>
```

These are the three hyperlinks, and as you see there are small images beside these links. Now what I want to achieve is, when say page MISSION is the active page, I want the image to be mission2.png (instead of mission.png originally, when that page was NOT the active page).

Hope the question is bit clearer now.

> **<>**>

Question on HTML/ CSS -

Example scenario - 
There are three webpages - About, Mission, Contact - and the links are such that you have a 10x10 pic beside each of these links like this:

```
[pic] About
[pic] Mission
[pic] Contact
```

(where [pic] stands for the corresponding 10x10 image).

I would like to design these hyperlinks such that the [pic] would be blue in color for the ACTIVE page, and all other [pics] would be black in color.

For example,suppose the user is on the MISSION page, then [pic] corresponding to Mission hyperlink would alone be BLUE, all others would be in BLACK.

Note- the blue and orange pics are same, only the color changes between each of these links.

Could you please guide me as to how to design this 'active page' hyperlink design? I know how to tag the link and the page with ids and then change the color of the hyperlink so that the active page's hyperlink would be in blue and others in black, but I seem to run out of ideas on how to change the corresponding 10x10 image also.

Comment: how do you mean 'blue in colour'? The image border of the actual image itself? Can you provide a sample of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @user597264 - 
probably, this website uses a similar concept (though not the idea of image and color..) - www.music.vettila.com
I basically want to achieve this rollover effect for the hyperlink (home/ about/ .. ) in the above website..

Comment: That site's not using images, it's simply a link within a list item with some nice CSS. When a page is active, like 'home', they're applying a background colour and radius to the list item (li) and changing the colour of the text on the link. Can you add your HTML to your question?

Comment: @yser597264 - I have updated the question to include more HTML code..

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
  <a>Menu Item 1</a>
  <a>Menu Item 2 </a>
  <a class="active">Current page</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu a
{
  background: some background;
}

#menu a.active
{
  background: some other background;
}
```

To prevent using multiple images for the menu items you can use an image [sprite sheet](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) that will save some rendering time.

All you need to do is work out how to get the current page and apply the active class in your language of choice, there are plenty of ways to do this.

Comment: THanks @Steve, but i believe what we are achieving is the styling of the link. What I intended was changing the IMAGE beside a link, when the page corresponding to the link is the active one. As in, i have a png image to display along with the text of the link. Now when this page becomes active, i want to change the image also.

Comment: You can set the image next to the link using background-image in CSS, position it to the left and pad the text in a bit. That way you won't need to include the extra markup in the HTML.

Comment: @Steve's way is much easier and more widely supportable then using a non CSS technique like JavaScript. One other thing is that you don't need #menu a.active it can just be #menu .active

Comment: Got it, so the image and the text of the link will be together, like - 
<a><img>text</a>...
But the problem is now when this link becomes the active page, how do i CHANGE the image as such..? i want the image to change from img1.png to img2.png...

Isnt this achievable using css..? should JS be used for this?

Comment: Close, you don't need the image tag at all inside the <a> tag. The image will be set purely through CSS. If you give the the menu items a set background image, and the menu item with the .active class applied a different background image, they will change accordingly.

Comment: ...also +1 to m4tt1mus. Not sure why I used a.active there!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to use `background img`s.

You can then change them on `hover`.

Also you can add an `active class` for each page and set the `background-img` for that too.

Comment: thanks, but I am not looking exactly at hover effects on a hyperlink. I would like to change the image beside a hyperlink when that particular page is active.

Comment: Ignoring what Jason said about on hover, you can set a class of 'active' to the current page on the menu and have a different background image display when this class is applied.

Comment: umm..thanks @steve, but could you please explain with some pseudo-code? I couldnt really get what you meant there. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're talking about a hover effect or just a static, this is the page you're on and so I am changing the color of the this image. It reads like that, but your link shows a roll over effect.

If you're looking to make a static change based on the page a user is currently here are two popular options for you.

1. Server side processing. Have the server figure out what page you're
   on and change the image path/CSS class for that specific link. This is can be
   done a million different ways and it all depends on your server-side
   processing (PHP, ASP.NET, etc)
2. Using something like jQuery to read what page the user is on from
   the address and then change the image path/CSS class to that page's link.